# Joomla add article via php script Application Instantiation Error

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

i created a script in order to insert some articles via a php script. This script is working on my local machine (xampp), but when i deploy the whole joomla project to my web server i get the following error message:

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Application Instantiation Error

By adding some echo calls, i was able to find the line which causes the error:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Now i am wondering how to fix this behaviour and make my function also run on the web server.

Below i will provide my system informations and the beginning of my php function until the line, which causes the error message:

---

#### Systeminformations

- joomla version: 3.6.5 Stable
- db version: 5.6.34-79.1-log
- php version: 5.6.30-he.0
- web server: Apache

---

#### PHP snippet

```
<?php

echo "STARTING;   ";

// get db connection
include('../includes/mysql.inc.php');

// get all sql querys
include('./autoNewsQuerys.inc.php');

/**
 * Prepare joomla framework to insert article correctly
 */
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE','/is/htdocs/wp1088688_4E1H7PYJFK/www');
    require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php');
    require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php');
    defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

echo "searching app;";
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
echo "Found app;";
```

---

#### Full browser output

> STARTING; searching app;Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/is/htdocs/wp1088688_4E1H7PYJFK/www/1500AutoNews/autoNews.php" at line 3.

So as you can see the error is caused by the JFactory call. 'Found app' is never printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the Joomla `index.php` file to another file and then replace the `$app->execute` code with your code.

Note: You don't need to include any `MySQL` library - since you are loading the Joomla environment then you have access to the JDatabase class, which is a database abstraction layer.

Another note: this file `autoNewsQuerys.inc.php` likely contains some issues (maybe you are trying to instantiate the app there, but the Joomla environment hasn't loaded yet). You should move it to the end.

Comment: thank you so much! I just copied the index.php file, changed the JPATH_BASE (thanks to @AmitRay) variable and replaced the execute call with my entire function. And its working now like a charm. But the question is: why?

Comment: I think because you were using in your code some core Joomla functionality, and you were loading your code before the Joomla environment was being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

if it was working on localhost and it is not working on Web server then the biggest issue is with defining the base path. Give a hardcoded base path of your joomla installation. I suggest you to check your base path using a php script. Create a php file and name it path.php. Put it in the Joomla main folder. Content of the file

```
<?php
echo "The Base path is ".getcwd();
?>
```

Once you get the path just change the Base_Path. For ex:

```
define('JPATH_BASE', '\var\www\joomla');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still its not working. I updated my question, as the php code (hardcoded base path) and the error message changed a bit.

Comment: @johni07 The only thing that can change when the server is changed is the path not the php or mysql functions. If the server is having same configuration but was working perfectly in localhost means only the path was changed nothing else. You just think once why it shouldnt work in new web server.